# Use of undeclared type 'JSONValue'

Tags: xcode

this piece of code is throwing the above error:

```
class func fromJSON(json: [JSONValue]) -> Artwork? {
```

I have imported SwiftyJSON as other articles have suggested to, however, the same error remains.

```
# Pods for Notice!
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: There is no `JSONValue` type in `SwiftJSON`.

Comment: @vadian which import should I be using?? Thanks :D

Comment: Maybe the tutorial you are using is outdated.